# GitLab will not allow me to push more than 1 small file

Tags: git, gitlab

I have used GitLab for over 6 months and since last week I have never had an issue pushing files to me repos. Now I get an error when I push more than 1 small file:

I have deleted repos, completely started again, uninstalled git on the server, etc etc to try to solve this but it still will not allow me to push slightly larger/more files:

When I push 1 file:

```
git push -u origin master

Username for 'https://gitlab.com': username
Password for 'https://username@gitlab.com': 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 385 bytes | 55.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://gitlab.com/pglover/HTSv2.git
   e5454ca..8147977  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

Pushing ~10 files (~10kb):

```
git push -u origin master

Username for 'https://gitlab.com': username
Password for 'https://username@gitlab.com': 
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 5.48 KiB | 224.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have searched for why this may happen and have increased the buffer settings:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But this does not help. I have also tried changing the url in .git/config

from:

```
    url = https://gitlab.com/username/repo.git
```

to:

```
    url = git@gitlab.com:username/repo.git
```

but the error that occurs then is:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Does anybody have any tips on where to look or what might be causing this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use ssh protocol instead of https?

Comment: You can try setting the environment variable GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 in order to get more information about what's failing.  Without knowing the cause of the 400, it's hard to say what the problem is.